# C# JavascriptSerializer inheritence

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, javascriptserializer

Using JavascriptSerializer, is there any way to deserialize json like :

```
{
   items:[
      {name:"item1", prop1:true, prop2:"prop"},
      {name:"item2", prop1:true, prop3:"prop", prop4:"prop"}
   ]
}
```

Is it possible to deserialize using these classes :

```
public abstract class Item
{
   public String name {get; set;}
   public bool prop1 {get; set;}
}

public class ItemA : Item
{
   public String prop2 {get; set;}
}

public class ItemB : Item
{
   public String prop3 {get; set;}
   public String prop4 {get; set;}
}
```

Thanks for help !

Comment: Your question is *very* misleading.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do what you want unless you went for a non-type safe approach like using `dynamic` e.g.

```
public class Container
{
    public List<dynamic> items { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is you have a list of *mixed* types which the `JavascriptSerializer` doesn't support.

Answer (score -1):

try this
paste your json string here http://json2csharp.com/  and generate the class and do the code

```
  public class Item
 {
public string name { get; set; }
public bool prop1 { get; set; }
public string prop2 { get; set; }
public string prop3 { get; set; }
public string prop4 { get; set; }
 }

 public class RootObject
{
public List<Item> items { get; set; }
}



string sValue ="{items:[{name:"item1", prop1:true, prop2:"prop"},{name:"item2", prop1:true, 
                  prop3:"prop", prop4:"prop"}]}


   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer ObjJSerializer = new         
                                         System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

   var Data = ObjJSerializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(sValue);
```